# multi gpu with axes dont match array?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, cnn, gpu

If I train a model using 2 GPUs, using `multi_gpu_model` and the `ModelCheckpoint` callback to save the best, it gives this error when calling `load_model` on the checkpoint saved model.

I would like to train the model using multiple gpus, but run it again on a single GPU. This seems to fail.

> keras version: 2.2.4-tf

My code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
def get_model():
    base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3), include_top=False)
    #base_model.trainable = False

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(base_model)
    model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(196, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()

    model = multi_gpu_model(model,gpus=2)

    #optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

    return model


prediction = [] for i, name in enumerate(model_names):
    model = get_model()
    model.load_weights(name)

    test_generator.reset()
    pred = model.predict_generator(
        generator=test_generator,
        steps = len(df_test)/BATCH_SIZE,
        verbose=1
    )
    prediction.append(pred)

y_pred = 

np.mean(prediction, axis=0)
> 
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-42-6636e5e21c1b> in <module>
>       2 for i, name in enumerate(model_names):
>       3     model = get_model()
> ----> 4     model.load_weights(name)
>       5 
>       6     test_generator.reset()
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)
>     160         raise ValueError('Load weights is not yet supported with TPUStrategy '
>     161                          'with steps_per_run greater than 1.')
> --> 162     return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
>     163 
>     164   @trackable.no_automatic_dependency_tracking
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py
> in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)    1413        
> saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f, self.layers)    1414   
> else:
> -> 1415         saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)    1416     1417   def _updated_config(self):
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers)
>     681     symbolic_weights = _legacy_weights(layer)
>     682     weight_values = preprocess_weights_for_loading(
> --> 683         layer, weight_values, original_keras_version, original_backend)
>     684     if len(weight_values) != len(symbolic_weights):
>     685       raise ValueError('Layer #' + str(k) + ' (named "' + layer.name +
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights,
> original_keras_version, original_backend)
>     306     weights = convert_nested_time_distributed(weights)
>     307   elif layer.__class__.__name__ in ['Model', 'Sequential']:
> --> 308     weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
>     309 
>     310   if original_keras_version == '1':
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in convert_nested_model(weights)
>     294             weights=weights[:num_weights],
>     295             original_keras_version=original_keras_version,
> --> 296             original_backend=original_backend))
>     297         weights = weights[num_weights:]
>     298     return new_weights
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights,
> original_keras_version, original_backend)
>     306     weights = convert_nested_time_distributed(weights)
>     307   elif layer.__class__.__name__ in ['Model', 'Sequential']:
> --> 308     weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
>     309 
>     310   if original_keras_version == '1':
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in convert_nested_model(weights)
>     282             weights=weights[:num_weights],
>     283             original_keras_version=original_keras_version,
> --> 284             original_backend=original_backend))
>     285         weights = weights[num_weights:]
>     286 
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights,
> original_keras_version, original_backend)
>     388         weights[1] = conv_utils.convert_kernel(weights[1])
>     389     if K.int_shape(layer.weights[0]) != weights[0].shape:
> --> 390       weights[0] = np.transpose(weights[0], (3, 2, 0, 1))
>     391       if layer.__class__.__name__ == 'ConvLSTM2D':
>     392         weights[1] = np.transpose(weights[1], (3, 2, 0, 1))
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in
> transpose(a, axes)
>     637 
>     638     """
> --> 639     return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
>     640 
>     641 
> 
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in
> _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
>      54 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
>      55     try:
> ---> 56         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
>      57 
>      58     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have
> 
> ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Comment: I am facing the same. Did you find solution? I tried quite a bit from top searches but to no avail so far.

Comment: I concluded this issue is caused by keras tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: No, it happens with keras 2.2.x on lower tensorflow as well. But, what did you use as workaround?